# How do I get sqlite3 to do regexp in Tcl

Tags: regex, sqlite, tcl

I'd like to include regexp in my Tcl project but when I run my code I get this error:

> no such function: REGEXP

my code looks like this:

```
return [brain eval "select * from bad WHERE input REGEXP '^(.){0}_'"]
```

I can test this exact code out in the database (I'm using BD browser for SQLite to browse the database) and it works correctly:

```
select * from uniq WHERE input REGEXP '^(.){1}0'
```

> 20 Rows returned from: select * from uniq WHERE input REGEXP
>   '^(.){1}0' (took 18ms)

So REGEXP will work in the browser, but not in my Tcl Script. Here's what I found so far on this issue:

1. someone else had the same problem in ruby: [How to turn on REGEXP in SQLite3 and Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839204/how-to-turn-on-regexp-in-sqlite3-and-rails-3-1)
2. Somone had the same problem in iOS and had to cretae_sqlite_function ["No such function: REGEXP" in sqlite3 on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312994/no-such-function-regexp-in-sqlite3-on-ios)
3. how to write a function in sqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html
4. How to write a function for sqlite in Tcl:
   https://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html
5. An example of the function I may have to write in ruby:
   https://github.com/sei-mi/sqlite3_ar_regexp/blob/master/lib/sqlite3_ar_regexp/extension.rb
6. REGEXP user function is not defined by default:
   http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp
7. A PHP example of the REGEXP user-defined Function:
   [How do I use regex in a SQLite query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query/18484596#18484596)

So I've come to the conclusion that I have to write some kind of function myself to get this to work, but I don't know what that function has to look like. Is it simply passing on the regular expression I make to sqlite3? or is it converting the regular expression to something else then passing it on?

Would the function look something like this?

```
file mkdir db
sqlite3 db ./brain/brain.sqlite -create true

db eval { create_function('regexp', 2) do |func, pattern, expression|
            func.result = expression.to_s.match(
            Regexp.new(pattern.to_s, Regexp::IGNORECASE)) ? 1 : 0
         end
         }
```

Thanks for any help or advice you can offer me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple to enable regular expression processing. All you have to do (assuming that `db` is your connection handle) is use the [`function` method](https://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html#function) like this:

```tcl
db function regexp -deterministic {regexp --}
```

This tells SQLite to create the function, that it is deterministic (as regular expression matching most certainly is) and that it should work by passing the arguments to `regexp --` (the `--` stops REs that begin with `-` from causing problems).

See for yourself from this session log:

```tcl
% package require sqlite3
3.8.10.2
% sqlite3 db :memory:
% db eval {select 1 where 'abc' regexp 'b'}
no such function: regexp
% db function regexp -deterministic {regexp --}
% db eval {select 1 where 'abc' regexp 'b'}
1
```

Comment: thanks! seems so simple but I never would have figured that out on my own! I also found, that LIKE, using "_" could handle most of what I am using regexp for, so that maybe a viable alternative for others with this problem.